# IOException when running the BAM samples

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I am tryying my hands on the WSO2 BAM.
I tried to run the examples (“HTTPD Logs Analysis” or “KPI Monitoring Sample”), but I get the following message after creating the toolbox, upon the publishing of data:

> java.io.IOException : Cannot run program in “C:\Program” (in directory “C:\wso2bam-2.3.0”): CreateProcess error=2 , The specified file cannot be found.

Any tips on this issue?

Comment: Since you're using windows have you installed Cygwin? Here are the prerequisites for BAM: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Installation+Prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

Some times in windows 'Programs Files' cause problem due to space in it. Therefore if you have WSO2 BAM distribution within C:\Program Files or you have space in the distribution path some where, please change it to a location without space.

And also check where your java installation is in. That also should be in a location which doesn't have space in the path.

Please check both, that will resolve your problem.